# Tap UIButton to create another UIButton programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I'm trying to create a UIButton programmatically. I have a button called "addCash" (which was already created in interface builder), upon tapping this button I want another button to dynamically appear. This button works fine when done in viewDidLoad, but this is not what I want as "addCash" needs to be tapped before this new button is to be created. This is what I have so far...

```
-(IBAction) addCash{
UIButton *theButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
theButton.frame = CGRectMake(80, 50, 150, 40);
[theButton setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(test:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[theButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:theButton]; 
}
```

Comment: Why create the button programmatically? Why not have it created in IB beforehand but with `hidden = YES`, and just unhide it when your first button is pressed?

Comment: You are leaking `theButton`. Why are you retaining it?

Comment: also why have you left out the sender from the method signature? i.e. -(IBAction) addCash:(id)sender {...} ??

Comment: I need to create the button programmatically because ultimately I plan to have an unknown number of buttons created (1 to 100)

Comment: @bennythemink adding `sender` is not required and if you don't use the value then why bother...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plain add a lot of buttons use `UITableView` [with custom cell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7). If you will just add new buttons to view you will get a performance issue - all you buttons will be loaded simultaneously. `UITableView` can manage this situation and unload unused cell's.